# Why $\mathbb E\left[\sup\frac{|Y_t-Y_s|}{|t-s|^\alpha }\right]<\infty$ imply $(Y_t)_t$ continuous?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $(Y_t)_t$ a stochastic process s.t. $$\mathbb E\left[\sup_{s,t\in [0,1], s\neq t}\frac{|Y_t-Y_s|}{|t-s|^\alpha }\right]<\infty,$$ with $\alpha >0$. Why does this implies that $(Y_t)_t$ is continuous a.s. ?

Does it come from the fact that if $\mathbb E[X]<\infty$ then $\mathbb P\{X<\infty\}=1$, and thus $$\mathbb P\left\{\sup_{s,t\in [0,1], s\neq t}\frac{|Y_t-Y_s|}{|t-s|^\alpha }<\infty\right\}=1.$$

Also
$$\mathbb P\left\{\sup_{s,t\in [0,1], s\neq t}\frac{|Y_t-Y_s|}{|t-s|^\alpha }<\infty\right\}\leq \mathbb P\left\{\frac{|Y_t-Y_s|}{|t-s|^\alpha}<\infty\right\}=1.$$

1) How can I continue ? Does it implies that there is $C>0$ s.t. 
$$\mathbb P\{|Y_t-Y_s|<C|t-s|^\alpha \}=1,$$
or that $$\mathbb P\{\exists C>0: |Y_t-Y_s|\leq C|t-s|^\alpha \}=1 \ \ ?$$

2) And will it implies that $$\mathbb P\{\lim_{t\to s}|Y_t-Y_s|\}=1 \ \ ?$$
If yes, why ? I don't understand why I can put the limit inside.

Comment: Assuming that $$C = \sup_{\substack{s, t \in [0, 1] \\ s \neq t}} \frac{|Y_t - Y_s|}{|t-s|^{\alpha}}$$ defines a random variable (which is far from being obvious, and in fact, reveals one of the technical subtleties that lie in the theory of stochastic processes), the hypothesis tells that $C$ is finite $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. and $$ \mathbb{P}\left[ |Y_t - Y_s| \leq C|t - s|^{\alpha} : s, t \in [0, 1] \right] = 1. $$thus the sample path $t \mapsto Y_t$ is $\mathbb{P}$-.a.s. $\alpha$-Holder continuous.

Comment: @SangchulLee: 1) Why $C$ is not obviously a random variable ? Is there a reference I can read ? 2) So I can't prove that $\mathbb P\{\lim_{t\to s}|Y_t-Y_s|=0\}=1$ ?

Comment: Uncountable operations are always problematic for measurability, and as such, there is no guarantee that $C$ is measurable. Likewise, events related to regularity of sample paths, such as $$\left\{ \lim_{t\to s} |Y_t - Y_s| = 1 \text{ for all } s \right\}=\bigcap_{s}\left\{ \lim_{t\to s} |Y_t - Y_s| = 1\right\},$$requires uncountable operations and hence are not necessarily measurable. The usual workaround to this issue is to consider a suitable modification, for instance, by appealing to [Kolmogorov-Chentsov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_continuity_theorem).

Comment: @SangchulLee: But don't we have that $$\{\lim_{t\to s}|Y_t-Y_s|=0\}=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N^*}\bigcup_{p\in\mathbb Q, p>0}\bigcap_{|s-t|<p, s,t\in \mathbb Q}\left\{|Y_t-Y_s|\leq \frac{1}{n}\right\} \ \ ?$$ So the event is measurable. An other thing, an other member (but his post has been deleted) says : there is $N$ of measure $0$ s.t. for all $\omega \notin N$, $|Y_t(\omega )-Y_s(\omega )|\leq C|t-s|^\alpha $ and thus $\lim_{t\to s}|Y_t(\omega )-Y_s(\omega )|=0$ for all $\omega \notin N$. What we write "with abuse notation" by $\mathbb P\{\lim_{t\to s}|Y_t-Y_s|=0\}=1$. Do you think it works ?

Comment: The right-hand side only captures the continuity at rational points, so this cannot equal the left-hand side without further assumptions.

Comment: @SangchulLee: Ok, it's nevertheless an I argument I often saw... Do you know which condition is necessary to have this proof valid ? And for the argument just below ? (with $N$ of measure $0$...) Thanks a lot for your time and your explanations

Comment: By the way, if $\{\lim_{t\to s}|Y_t-Y_s|\}$ is not measurable, how can yes say that $(Y_t)_t$ is a.s. continuous ? (because we can't measure it)... It doesn't make sense, does it ? @SangchulLee

Comment: That is why it is important to set up a correct path space to begin with. For instance, if $I=[0,\infty)$ and $W=(W_t)_{t\in I}$ is a Brownian motion on $(\mathbb{R}^I,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^I),\mathbb{P})$, then the event $C=C(I,\mathbb{R})$ that sample paths are continuous is not in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^I)$. But Kolmogorov-Chenstov theorem tells that $W$ has a modification whose sample paths are continuous, hence we may instead consider the space $C$ equipped with the trace $\sigma$-algebra $\{B\cap C:B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^I)\}=\sigma(\pi_t|_{C}:t\in I)$.

Comment: For the Brownian motion so realized, now it makes sense to discuss continuity of sample paths, supremum over nice sets, and so forth, within measure theory.

Comment: @SangchulLee: So at the end, is it correct to say : from your first comment, there is $N$ of measure $0$ and $C>0$ s.t. $|Y_t(s)-Y_s(\omega )|\leq C|t-s|^\alpha $ for all $\omega \notin N$. Therefore, $\lim_{t\to s}|Y_t(\omega )Y_s(\omega )|=0$ for all $\omega \notin \Omega $, and thus $(Y_t)_t$ is a.s. continuous. **Is this correct ?** (but I still in truble with the fact that $\lim_{t\to s}Y_t=Y_s$ a.s. but the event $\{\lim_{t\to s}Y_t=Y_s\}$ may be not measurable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Assume that $Y = (Y_t)_{t\in[0, 1]}$ is realized over a [*complete probability space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space#Complete_probability_space) $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ such that the function $C : \Omega \to [0, \infty]$ defined by

  $$ C(\omega) = \sup_{\substack{s, t \in [0, 1] \\ s \neq t}} \frac{|Y_s(\omega) - Y_t(\omega)|}{|s-t|^{\alpha}} $$

  is measurable, then

  1. If $\omega \in \Omega$ is such that $C(\omega) < \infty$, then $|Y_t(\omega) - Y_s(\omega)| \leq C(\omega)|t - s|^{\alpha}$ for all $s, t \in [0, 1]$ and hence $t \mapsto Y_t(\omega)$ is $\alpha$-Holder continuous. In particular,
     $$ E := \{ \omega : t \mapsto Y_t(\omega) \text{ is continuous} \}$$
     satisfies
     $$ E^{c} \subseteq \{ \omega : C(\omega) = \infty \} $$
  2. If in addition that $\mathbb{E}[C] < \infty$, then $\{ C = \infty\}$ is measurable and $\mathbb{P}[C = \infty] = 0$. Since the probability space is complete, this implies that $E^c$ is also a measurable null-set. Therefore $E$ is also measurable and $\mathbb{P}[E] = 1$, i.e. the sample path is $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. continuous.
- It is worth to notice that $C$ and $E$ need not be measurable for any choice of the base probability space. For instance, under the naive choice $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}) = (\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}))$, one can prove that

  $$ C([0, 1], \mathbb{R}) = \{ \omega \in \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]} : \omega \text{ is continuous} \} \notin \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}). $$

  (This is because, for any $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]})$, there exists $I \subset [0, 1]$ such that $I$ is at most countable and $A$ is determined only by the information at times $t \in I$, i.e., $A \in \sigma( \pi_t : t \in I)$, where $\pi_t : \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the projection $\pi_t(\omega) = \omega_t$.) This tells that, in order to discuss regularity of sample paths, one needs to choose a suitable base probability space to begin with.

  If one is given a stochastic process $S$, the usual workaround is to show that $X$ satisfies some weaker notion of stochastic continuity, and then show that this notion allows to construct a modification which has continuous sample paths. For instance, If $W = (W_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is the Brownian motion, then it satisfies $\mathbb{E}[|W_s - W_t|^2] = |s - t|$, hence by Kolmogorov-Chenstov theorem, $W$ has a modification whose sample paths are continuous. Then one may realize this modification on a nice probability space where sample-path continuity can be discussed as measurable event.